# Cache loader data across fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

I have plenty of `Fragment`s and some of them load the same data but the data is used in different ways in conjuction with other data.

Right now I use the `Activity`s LoaderManager (`getActivity.getLoaderManager()` so that data is kept across the activity).

Would it be better to use a class with static variables? Do I gain or lose anything with that solution, comparing to how I am doing it right now?